# Extracted a line from meminfo, how do I display the result in bytes?

Tags: linux

I am using the following command to extract a specific line from meminfo:

```
awk '/MemTotal/' /proc/meminfo
```

This gives me the following result:

> MemTotal:        6418448 kB

I need to be able to take this line and convert it into bytes for an assignment. Can I do that within my existing command? Or would I need to take an entirely different approach in order to do so? I've found information on how to convert the entire meminfo list from kB into B, but I can't figure out how to do it for just one extracted line. I also couldn't figure out how to adapt commands I've seen for this to only extract one line.

Comment: Create an associative array that maps suffixes like `kB` and `mB` to a multiplier, then multiply the number by that to get the real total.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: I wonder what that assignment is for, but that's just me.

Comment: I think the point of the assignment is to force me to learn commands. I ultimately need to turn this into a mini shell that can extract some specific memory and system information, and all the memory information is meant to be displayed in bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean convert the kB to bytes,`awk '/MemTotal/ {print $2*1024}' /proc/meminfo`.
If you mean you want the result as bytes instead of text, pipe to `od -`c`

Comment: You are correct in the first assumption of what I meant! I feel a little stupid that it's that simple, but I really appreciate the help!

Comment: carterHa, awk is very flexible. We all overlooks simple solutions sometimes.